# fundamental region for the rotational symmetry group of a tetrahedron

Tags: geometry, group-theory, symmetry

How would I find the fundamental region of a tetrahedron for its rotational symmetry group $\mathcal{T}$?

I can think of how to find these regions in 2 dimensions, but I can't wrap my mind around the third dimension.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you see how the group of rotations on the equilateral triangle is naturally a proper subgroup of $\mathcal{T}$? Certainly then, the fundamental region of the triangle under this action (seen as a subspace of the tetrahedron) will be a subset of a fundamental region for $\mathcal{T}$. Try to visualise the action of $\mathcal{T}$ on this region. Does it miss any areas of the tetrahedron in its orbit?

Comment: Aha! I see :) Thank you so much. Is there a method or algorithm in general such that if I am given a regular polyhedron and its full symmetry group, I can use this method to construct its fundamental region? Or maybe such an method is unnecessary since there are only 5 regular polyhedra?

Comment: I know of a specific algorithm which works for finding fundamental domains of discrete group actions on a space called the hyperbolic plane. I imagine this method can be suitably modified. Let $\mathcal{G}$ be a group action on a manifold $X$. Take a point $x\in X$ which isn't fixed by any element of $\mathcal{G}$ (such a point exists for polyhedrons - prove it). Consider the orbit $\mathcal{G}x$ of the point $x$ and let $D$ be the set of all points in $X$ which are closer to $x$ than any other point in the orbit $\mathcal{G}x$. Under suitable conditions...

Comment: ...(which I'm not *entirely* sure of right now) $D$ will be a fundamental region of the action $\mathcal{G}$. That $D$ is well defined will also rely on some properties of $X$ and $\mathcal{G}$ which I'm not totally sure of. Note that $D$ can be constructed as the intersection of *half regions* which are the sets $D_g=\{y\in X|d(y,x)\leq d(y,g.x)\}$ of points closer to $x$ than a single action of $x$ by the element $g$. Clearly then $D=\bigcap_{g\in G}D_g$. Finding these half regions can be done with fairly basic geometry (perpendicular bisectors and the like).

Comment: Hmm, it does sound pretty interesting. Thank you for your explanation, I will look into this method.

Comment: The method I described might be a little *too* general. Given some regular polyhedron, I would look only at the orbit of an arbitrary point intersected with a single face. Perform the above algorithm, and then check to see if the constructed region has an orbit which covers the polyhedron. I'm fairly certain this will be enough because any face of the polyhedron can be translated to any other by some group action. Apologies if my explanation wasn't at the right level. I was working it out for myself as I was writing.